# How to add tooltip to a disabled select element using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have a disabled select element as follows for which I am not able to view the tooltip.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <select id="docpreset_colorformat" class="select2" name="docpreset_format_to" placeholder="Document format to"></select>
</div>
```

Jquery to disable:

```
$("#docpreset_colorformat").prop("disabled", true);
```

The jquery for adding the tooltip

```
$("#docpreset_colorformat").prop('title', 'Disabled for selected doc type: ' + format_to);
```

The tooltips works for other elements on the page such as of type 'input'.

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Any help would be appreciated such as a link to an old post or a hint.

Comment: Your selector is wrong. The select element hasn't id `docpreset_colorformat`

Comment: What plugin you use are using for the select control and what framework, maybe Bootstrap?. Also, if you can make a snippet showing the issue, that will be very useful.

Comment: @Mohammad, it was an example. I have many other select elements

Comment: If your selector be correct, the code work. http://jsfiddle.net/ugdva2qp/

Comment: @D.Smania,I'm not using a plugin. But bootstrap + Jquery and C# MVC

Comment: @BinoyCherian Check console that any return any error?

Comment: @Mohammad, thanks, let me check the console and I'm sure the selectors are good

Comment: @BinoyCherian Also check what the class `select2` is for, you sure not using the select2 plugin?

Comment: @D.Smania, yes I'm using the select2. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some research and the [select2](https://select2.org/) plugin don't offer any option (actually) for disable the default title that is rendered for the current selected option. So this is my approach:

**1)** Disable the rendering of title with the selected value, using next workaround:

```
$('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');
```

**2)** Add a wrapper container element to the selection control, and setup the title you want to render to this wrapper. In the example I'm showing, I use a `<spam>` element like the wrapper.

Check next example, the first selection control have implemented the workaround explained previously, while the other is standard:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Initialize select2 controls.

    $(".select2").select2();
    
    // Workaround for disable title rendering on the select2 plugin.

    $('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');

    // Customize the "#sel1" control.

    $("#sel1").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#sel1").parent().prop("title", "Custom title for select control");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-6">
    <spam>
    <select id="sel1" class="select2 form-control" placeholder="Placeholder...">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </spam>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <select id="sel2" class="select2 form-control" placeholder="Placeholder...">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```